# Maven 3 build failure: A required class is missing: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner

Tags: java, build, maven-3, spring-3

I am running the "hello world" canned project off of spring.io (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

I am using JDK7 and Maven 3.0.3. I have cleared my local maven repo entirely to start with a clean slate. The build fails consistently with the message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) on project gs-rest-service: Execution
>   default-resources of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed:
>   Unable to load the mojo 'resources' in the plugin
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6'. A required
>   class is missing: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner

With "mvn -X clean install", I get a detailed report, excerpts from which are given below:

> $ mvn -X clean install 
>   //...
>   Downloaded:
>   https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
>   (60 KB at 116.9 KB/sec) Feb 08, 2015 2:26:54 PM
>   org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.NamedClass WARNING: Error injecting:
>   org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner //...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
>           ... 73 more
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE //...

My pom.xml is as follows:

> //...    org.springframework
>       gs-rest-service
>       0.1.0
>
> ```
> <parent>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
> </parent>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
>             <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
>             <version>3.0</version>
>    </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
> <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>       <version>3.2</version>
>        <dependencies>
>             <dependency>
>                 <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
>                 <version>3.0</version>
>             </dependency>
>         </dependencies>
>     </plugin>
>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>   <repositories>
>     <repository>
>       <id>plexus-releases</id>
>       <url> http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/
>       </url>
>     </repository>
>     <repository>
>         <id>spring-releases</id>
>         <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
> <pluginRepositories>
>     <pluginRepository>
>       <id>plexus-releases</id>
>       <url>http://search.maven.org/</url>
>     </pluginRepository>
>     <pluginRepository>
>         <id>spring-releases</id>
>         <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
>     </pluginRepository>
> </pluginRepositories>
> ```

Any help greatly appreciated - I have tried cleaning the repo, adding the dependencies specifically for the plugin - all of no avail.

Thanx - Kobe

Comment: Your configuration with the repositories is just rubbish. Throw the complete part in your pom with the parts `<repositories>` and `pluginRepositories>` away cause maven has it's default (maven central). Furthermore why are you using an older Maven version 3.0.3 instead of an up-to-date one (3.2.5) or at least Maven 3.0.5. Why have you added the plexus-utils to the configuration for maven-compiler-plugin? Special reason?